# In Visual Studio 2019 is there a way to multi caret copy and paste?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Other IDEs I can for example place a caret at the end of `this.` on each line and then highlight and copy the contents of the rest of the line and then paste it.

At first it looks like this

```
this.emailaddr = 
this.firstname = 
this.lastname =
```

Then after the paste it looks like this

```
this.emailaddr = emailaddr = 
this.firstname = firstname = 
this.lastname = lastname =
```

Since each caret is now at the end of each line I simply back space 2 times and add `;` to finish

```
this.emailaddr = emailaddr;
this.firstname = firstname; 
this.lastname = lastname;
```

However In Visual Studio I get this when I paste

```
            this.emailaddr = emailaddr =
firstname =
lastname =

            this.firstname = emailaddr = 
firstname = 
lastname = 

            this.lastname = emailaddr = 
firstname = 
lastname =
```

Is this just an issue with Visual Studio code copying the contents to only one clipboard. Why in other IDE's each caret has its own memory for copy? Is there a setting to configure in Visual Studio?

Comment: It's not that each caret has its own memory per se; most sensible editors take the approach of "if the number of cursors and the number of clip lines are the same, then paste one line of the clipboard per cursor. Otherwise, paste the clipboard at each cursor". VS doesn't; [the world complained](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/multi-caret-copycut-paste-behaviour/408315) and because MS did nothing about it for years [a kind person decided to fix it via extesnion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VaclavNadrasky.MultiCaretBooster)

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension on the marketplace that does this called **Multiple Carets Booster**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VaclavNadrasky.MultiCaretBooster